# How can I configure Webpack output to include some options only for a particular bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have a Webpack 4 that build multiple bundles, I want to attach the output options `libraryTarget` & `library` for a single bundle only.

so it would look like this by default:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
```

except for a single bundle, I need the following:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: '[name]'
  },
```

is this possible? I'm not seeing an example in the document

Comment: No. You have to build them with different webpack config files. The library target applies to the library itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking, but you can instead use your existing configuration as a "common" configuration and extend it in another using [`webpack-merge`](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge):

```
// e.g. webpack.config.your-lib.js
module.exports = merge(require('./webpack.config.common.js'), {
  // ...entry changes...
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: '[name]',
  }
})
```

Don't forget to make amendments to the `entry` in the above so the new config is building only the intended library bundles.